# Copying data of one database to another in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, postgresql

I am using Oracle database but open to use other database so tagging all of them.

I am `designing` one system in which I have to inject all the `data` of existing `database table` into `new database` and whatever changes happens in existing database should reflect in new database on daily basis. My approach is.

I will copy all the `data` of existing `database` to new `database`.
Then I will create a `trigger` which will record all the changes in the `table` and store in another `table(all the DML operations)`.

Once in a day my API will read the data generated by trigger and copy into new system.  I don't need live data so I will schedule job only once in a day to copy `data` into new `database`

is this the proper approach? any suggestions?

Comment: You're basically describing database replication. Check if your dbms does this out of the box.

Comment: Please indicate only the database you are using. You have 4 selected. If the 2 databases in question are different DBMS please indicate each in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Common practice would be to back up your primary instance and restore it on the secondary once a day.

You could schedule the backup and restore in sequence as a daily jobs.

Comment: Only way to inject data in destination system is using API. I need to write data into json format  before inserting into another syste. thats why i need to maintain middle tier to add data.

Answer (score 1):

If your copy database is Sql server, then I suggested you use **LinkedServer**. Based on the documentation:

> Linked servers enable you to implement distributed databases that can
> fetch and update data in other databases. They are a good solution in
> the scenarios where you need to implement database sharding without
> need to create a custom application code or directly load from remote
> data sources. Linked servers offer the following advantages:
>
> The ability to access data from outside of SQL Server.
>
> The ability to issue distributed queries, updates, commands, and
> transactions on heterogeneous data sources across the enterprise.
>
> The ability to address diverse data sources similarly.
>
> You can find more information based on the documentation.

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15